# data merge not generating multiple records.

Tags: adobe-indesign, mac, data-merge

I need to know what i'm doing wrong.

i'm making a catalog that needs 4 images per page. as so. 
[image: desired result]
i know i can't do that with facing pages so i separated the two pages and created individual file for each page.

i'm running in to a problem when trying to generate mulitple records per page, from the tutorials and other forum posts i've read i SHOULD be setting it up right... but its not working.

here is the set up that i THINK i'm doing right. 
[image: doc setup]

data merge options. 
[image: options]

[image: detailed options]

as you can see, its only generating 1 record per page... i need 4. since i have over 500 records that i don't want to do by hand.

Comment: ok i figured it out.  i was putting NON-REPEATING elements on the page where my preview was. when i should have put them on the master page instead. leaving first page of the layout to generate the rest of the document.  problem solved.

Comment: Should post your comment as an answer and mark it as so (might have to wait a day to mark it correct) so others might benefit from this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok i figured it out. i was putting NON-REPEATING elements on the page where my preview was. when i should have put them on the master page instead. leaving **first** page of the layout to generate the rest of the document. problem solved.